# Confusion with semantic HTML

Tags: html

I am new to HTML and wanted to ask you guys about the difference between

```
<header>
<div id="showcase"></div>
</header>
```

AND

```
<div id="showcase">
<header>
</header>
</div>
```

Are both the same?

Comment: They are different, of course, but whether the difference matters depends on your actual code. In most cases (but not knowing what `showcase` is to be used for) the second is probably more "correct", for suitable values of "correct".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A `div` is an arbitrary division of content. It doesn't really have a semantic meaning, only that what is inside a div is something separated from what's outside the div. It's the default element people use to make a block to which a class can be applied when there isn't a semantically proper element to use.

`div` were pretty much everywhere at a time when the HTML language wasn't really being developed with as much of a focus on semantics and separation of concerns, and there were no `header`, `footer`, `section` or `nav` elements.

The answer to your question really depends on the context, but I'd say putting a `div` inside a `header` means that whatever is inside the `div` is something that is separated in some way from the rest of the `header`. Meanwhile putting a `header` inside a `div` means that what's inside the `div` including the `header` is part of something that is separated from what surrounds them.

...but long story short, unless a CSS hack relies on it, you should just drop the div if you've got nothing else than a header. The `header` tag was made to replace `div` with something more meaningful.

Comment: The id suggests that the div is there for a reason (even if it doesn't give it any tangible semantics), so removing it outright without an appropriate replacement for it probably isn't the best option...

Comment: True, there might be a situation where a wrapper is needed. But I find it silly when I see people do things like `<div><nav><ul><li><div>foo</div></li><li><div>bar</div></li></ul></nav></div>` when they only needed `<nav><a>foo</a><a>bar</a></nav>`. Keeping things readable should be a priority in my book.

Comment: @Jacque Goupil, thank you dude for your great explanation. So, the context is to put navigation bar and showcase area( with jumbotron class) right below nav bar. Do I have to use the second option with header inside div?

Comment: My question would be: why do you need a div in the first place?

Comment: @JacqueGoupil, :) I just was watching tutorials on YouTube and author decided to use header inside div so as to put nab bar and showcase inside header. I thought div is put inside header but the author used in a different way. Here is link so you get what I mean:https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GJXXf3_dcng&t=593s

Comment: I honestly wouldn't have put any div there, but in this case it's not that big of a deal.

Answer (score 1):

HTML5 elements like `<header>`, `<nav>`, and `<section>` are usually used to define high-level, broad markup areas, often with more generic HTML used inside them – so your first example makes more semantic sense to me.

But that's making one big assumption: That your site has a `<header>` area and inside that header you're placing a 'showcase' componemt of some sort. Your example 1 fits that structure

BUT: Technically you ***could*** have a component on your page called a 'showcase', and THAT showcase ***could*** have its own `<header>`. Lots of pages/apps have a single `<header>`, but there's nothing stopping you from have multiple headers on a single page/app. That's your second example.

So either could be semantically correct depending on the structure of your site.

PS: I'm assuming your `<header></header>` snippet would contain other HTML in the real world?

Of course, you could just add the ID to the header.

```
<header id="showcase">
<div>... </div>
</header>
```

Comment: You bring up a good point. I'll add that `section` tags define the document's outline while a `header` tag only indicates the role of its content, so their use is less strictly defined. `header` says: my content is the header of something. `section` says: the document or article I am a part of is divided into sections and here is one of them. For more info on this, read: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_HTML_sections_and_outlines